# Week number to week commencing date USING PYTHON?

Tags: python, date, python-datetime

```
n=10
```

I want to get the week commencing date of the 10th week of the current year (2022), i.e., 3/7/2022. How can this be done using datetime functions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the %W directive, but you also need to specify what the start day is of the week and of course the year.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime("10-2022-1", "%W-%Y-%w"))
```

Result:

```
2022-03-07 00:00:00
```

1. 10 is the week number
2. 2022 is the year
3. 1 is the day of the week to start with (Monday) in order to get an actual date.

Datetime formats: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes